Central force motion happens in 2d instead of 3d (Lagrangian Formalism argument)
What is the argument purely from Lagrangian formalism (without using forces), that the Lagrangian of a mass in a central force would exhibit motion in 2 dimensions as opposed to 3 dimensions?
Details:
The Lagrangian in central force must be:
$L = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{r}^2+\frac{1}{2}mr^2\dot{\theta}^2+\frac{1}{2}m(r\sin\theta)^2\dot{\phi}^2-U(r)$
I saw in several notes, people eliminate the $\phi$ coordinate using the fact that angular momentum $\vec{L}$ is conserved, and hence the motion must happen in 2d. But I feel that this uses elements of Newtonian Mechanics. Is there a purely lagrangian argument using the fact that the potential is that of a central force and hence there must only be two generalized coordinates instead of two?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/328100/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1486/2451 and links therein.

In Goldstein, near the end after having Hamilton-Jacobi equation and all, there is a derivation that did not assume that $\vartheta=\frac\pi2$, and instead worked tirelessly to extract that $\vartheta$ and $\varphi$ motion are coupled exactly. The frequencies must be the same. In that way, the text proves that the motion must be in 2D.
